# adding the images to facebook news feed on a website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I found a good tutorial and code on how to display a Facebook news feed into a website at this website http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website/, the only downside is that it doesn't show how to put the images as part of the news feed.  This feed only shows how to put the text.  The problem is that the client I have updates pictures on his website and the text supports the pictures so without displaying the pictures the text makes no sense.  The code I am using is listed in the link above.

My working test site has the file I am working with. it is http://www.twmtest.com and if you go to the about-us page it shows what I have gotten to display.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code inside the lines `echo '<li>';` and `echo '</li>';`:

```
if (!empty($news->picture)) {
  printf ('<img src="%s" alt="Image from Facebook" />', $news->picture);
}
```

There is a lot of data returned by that one API call. You can `print_r($news);` to see all of it, or visit the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to get a better look at it.

Comment: Awesome!, it worked, thank you very much.  Now i just need to get it dressed up with some CSS and I should be good to go.